# How can I find the direction of a Vector2 with only the X and Y coordinates?

Tags: math, xna

I would like to know 2 things about the struct Vector2 in XNA:

1. Why does this struct only have X and Y instead of X,Y (origin) and X',Y' (destination)?
2. How can I calculate the direction of a vector with only the X,Y?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Kind Regards.
Josema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) A vector does not need length.

2) The numbers themselves determine the direction of the vector.  Think of the cartesian plane.  If you have a negative x and a positive y, then you are going top left...positive x, positive y, top right...etc. etc.

Comment: Not quite true... a vector has a length (norm) by definition. However, a vector does not need _location_ in terms of a coordinate system.

Answer (score 15):

The origin is usually assumed to be (0,0).

Comment: ...and based on this assumption, both direction AND length can be determined.

Answer (score 3):

The X and Y are not actually the coordinates of a point.

They are X-axis and Y-axis components of the vector. A vector by definition has no origin, it represents only **direction** and **length**, not **position**.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically a vector has orientation (direction) and magnitude (length). It does not have position. When vectors are used in graphics programming to represent positions they are implicitly representing a point as an offset from the origin.

If you want to convert from a vector to an angle you can use simple trigonometry - the x and y components form two sides of a triangle and you can calculate the angle the vector makes with any axis. If you want to find the angle between two arbitrary vectors a and b it's `acos(dot(a, b) / (length(a) * length(b))`.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the direction (angle) of a vector most languages have an atan2(y,x) function.